# Vue.js v-html contenteditable prevent dom refresh to keep cursor / caret from jumping

Tags: javascript, vue.js, contenteditable, caret

For reference I'm using Vue 2.0, Vuex, and Firebase.

I am building a contenteditable component using the v-html binding to render the innerHTML. The data is updated onKeyUp. Whenever the data is updated the DOM element refreshes with the "new" data, causing the caret / cursor to jump back to the beginning of the contenteditable div.

I have looked into Rangy and a few other stackoverflow solutions, but I feel the easiest solution would be to unbind the DOM element from the data refresh. I would like for the data to still update in firebase but not result in an element refresh.

Is there a way for me to still use v-html but prevent the DOM element from refreshing with the data? Or is there another way to render the HTML without auto binding?

**Edit: 11/18/16**

So I’ve continued to work on a fix for this. Here are my current ideas.

1. Use a [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) and stop component re-render. I’ve looked through the Vue docs but can’t seem to find something to stop the cycle.
2. Use something like [React’s “componentShouldRender”](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). Again, it doesn’t look like Vue.js has a comparable method in the lifecycle.

If anybody knows of any methods to end the lifecycle, stop re-render, or a way to get React's "componentShouldRender" functionality out of vue, that should be enough fix this issue.

-

**Update: 11/29/16**

This update is a little late coming. I've logged a [feature request](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4255) with Vue on Github.

There are a few JSFiddles in the issue discussion which could provide a [potential solution](https://jsfiddle.net/9upfskLy/). However none of them I believe qualifies as a complete solution. The only promising one has recently yielded [more issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877280/vue-js-force-re-render-of-component-which-contains-v-once-directive).

All of these problems would be non-issues with the addition of a `componentShouldRender` lifecycle hook. I will continue to look for a complete solution

Comment: make jsfiddle pls

Comment: Searching for a smiliar problem, I found this in the docs : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy apparently you can add :lazy to your v-model directive, in order for the model to update on change events only. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it may help you handle it

Comment: @lkostka it's actually `.lazy`. but I tried it with no change :/

Comment: Brrrrr then I don't know I guess you'll have to plug some custom event management there. Hope someone smarter will post a solution.

Comment: If it were an input, I'd suggest re-focus after the dom's refreshed with some lifecycle hook. Not sure what's with "editable div".

Comment: I think I answered a similar question a few weeks back which may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40151014/vuejs-2-v-for-key-not-working-html-being-replaced/40154101#40154101

Comment: @craig_h I was able to look over that one before submitting this question. Unfortunately I don't think their case quite matches my criteria. See my update and attached JSFiddles for a better idea.

Comment: @Jason, did you added components to your `contenteditable` and stored user input to database? Did you made the ability to edit stored to database content?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way for me to still use v-html but prevent the DOM element from refreshing with the data?

Yes. The `v-once` directive does exactly this.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [**@woodberry**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8112869/woodberry) simply add the **v-once** directive to the content editable div. Here is an example implementation:

```
<div v-once v-html="content" :contenteditable="true" @input="onInput"></div>
```

Then the onInput() method could handle the value changes:

```
onInput(event) {

    this.content = event.target.innerText
}
```

Then set the content as a reactive property

```
data() {
    return {
        content: ''
    }
},
```

Try the example above with and without the **v-once** directive to see the difference.